# R.3 standardization: what is the command for custom stadardization

Tags: r

I want to standardize a data set with mean= 3 and std dev =1/3 ; Is there any command to do it?
Scale is for mean =0 , std dev =1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet from the documentation of `scale` (`?scale`).

> Usage
>
> scale(x, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
>
> Arguments
>
> `x` a numeric matrix(like object).
>
> `center`   either a logical value or a vector of length equal to the number of columns of x.
>
> `scale` either a logical value or a numeric vector of length equal to the
>   number of columns of x.

The following will do exactly as you wanted.

```
scale(x, center = 3, scale = 1/3)
```

As a check, try

```
(x-3)/(1/3)
```